# Swift CGPoint in relation to another CGPoint

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, cgrect, cgpoint

I am trying to have two UIButtons. One is 8 points from the edge of the UIView they are inside and the second one is 4 points from the start of the first.  I am currently doing this

```
    let buttonFrames: CGSize = CGSizeMake(56, 42)
    let buttonRightPosition: CGPoint = CGPointMake(frame.size.width - 8, frame.size.height - 62)
    let buttonLeftPosition: CGPoint = CGPointMake(buttonRightPosition - 60, frame.size.height)
```

Both buttons will have the frame 56x42 but I will also add size to fit both buttons. So, that is why I need to adjust the second one accordingly. When I do this an error occurs in variable buttonLeftPosition. I am trying to find any way to place a view in relation to another view in the same class.

Comment: so...what's your question?

Answer (score 1):

`buttonRightPosition` is a `CGPoint`. In your last line, when you are trying to create the `buttonLeftPosition` `CGPoint`, you have to use `buttonRightPosition.x` to access its `x` position..

Note: In Swift I would use the `CGSize` and `CGPoint` initializers instead of `CGSizeMake()` or `CGPointMake()`

```
let buttonFrames = CGSize(width: 56, height: 42)
let buttonRightPosition = CGPoint(x: frame.size.width - 8, y: frame.size.height - 62)
let buttonLeftPosition = CGPoint(x: buttonRightPosition.x - 60, y: frame.size.height)
```